# Liferay hangs in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to set up Liferay in `docker` using `docker-compose` for the first time. I have to admit, I am new to Liferay.
I used the liferay-gradle task `./gradlew buildDockerImage` to generate a docker folder (with all required build files) under `build` which has everything needed to setup a working container, I then wrote this `docker-compose` file to use that image and generated files in order to build a self-contained liferay project containing `mysql`, `elasticsearch`, `kibana`, and `liferay`, my `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:



  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./scripts/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
    networks:
      - lfnet
    restart: unless-stopped


  es01:
    container_name: es1
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ES_STACK_VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - lfnet
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - bootstrap.system_call_filter=false
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - ES_SKIP_SET_KERNEL_PARAMETERS=true
      - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es2,es3
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1




  es02:
    container_name: es2
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ES_STACK_VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - lfnet
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - bootstrap.system_call_filter=false
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - ES_SKIP_SET_KERNEL_PARAMETERS=true
      - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es1,es3
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1






  es03:
    container_name: es3
    depends_on:
      - es02
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ES_STACK_VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - lfnet
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - esdata03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - bootstrap.system_call_filter=false
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - ES_SKIP_SET_KERNEL_PARAMETERS=true
      - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es1,es2
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1




  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - es02
      - es03
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${ES_STACK_VERSION}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - lfnet
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}





  liferay:
    container_name: liferay
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
    build:
      context: ../build/docker
      dockerfile: ../../docker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - es02
      - es03
      - mysql
    environment:
      LIFERAY_RETRY_PERIOD_JDBC_PERIOD_ON_PERIOD_STARTUP_PERIOD_DELAY: 10
      LIFERAY_RETRY_PERIOD_JDBC_PERIOD_ON_PERIOD_STARTUP_PERIOD_MAX_PERIOD_RETRIES: 10
      LIFERAY_JVM_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
      - ${LF_PORT}:8080
      - ${LF_GOGO_PORT}:11311
    networks:
      - lfnet


# Volumes
volumes:
  liferay-data:
  liferay-osgi-configs:
  liferay-osgi-marketplace:
  liferay-osgi-modules:
  liferay-osgi-war:


  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
  esdata03:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
  mysqldata:
    driver: local







# Networks
networks:
  lfnet:
    driver: bridge
```

So far all the containers seem to work fine except `Liferay`, for some reason, it gets stuck here and does not reach a point where it is accessible:

```
    [LIFERAY] To SSH into this container, run: "docker exec -it 255c0c98fb63 /bin/bash".

    [LIFERAY] Executing scripts in /usr/local/liferay/scripts/pre-configure:

    [LIFERAY] Executing 100_liferay_image_setup.sh.
    [LIFERAY] Copying /home/liferay/configs/local config files:

    /home/liferay/configs/local
    └── portal-ext.properties

    [LIFERAY] ... into /opt/liferay.


    [LIFERAY] The directory /mnt/liferay/files does not exist. Create the directory $(pwd)/xyz123/files on the host operating system to create the directory /mnt/liferay/files on the container. Files in /mnt/liferay/files will be copied to /opt/liferay before Liferay Portal starts.

    [LIFERAY] Executing scripts in /mnt/liferay/scripts:

    [LIFERAY] The directory /mnt/liferay/deploy is ready. Copy files to $(pwd)/xyz123/deploy on the host operating system to deploy modules to Liferay Portal at runtime.

    [LIFERAY] Starting Liferay Portal. To stop the container with CTRL-C, run this container with the option "-it".
```

My `liferay` Dockerfile looks like this:

```
    FROM liferay/portal:7.2.0-ga1
    ENV LIFERAY_WORKSPACE_ENVIRONMENT=dev
    COPY --chown=liferay:liferay deploy /mnt/liferay/deploy
    COPY --chown=liferay:liferay patching /mnt/liferay/patching
    COPY --chown=liferay:liferay scripts /mnt/liferay/scripts
    COPY --chown=liferay:liferay configs /home/liferay/configs
    COPY --chown=liferay:liferay 100_liferay_image_setup.sh /usr/local/liferay/scripts/pre-configure/100_liferay_image_setup.sh
```

I am confused, I do not understand why the `Liferay` container hangs at `Starting Liferay Portal. To stop the container with CTRL-C, run this container with the option "-it".`,
I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but did you try giving your JVM a bit more memory? Liferay is known to require quite a bit of memory & CPU.

```
LIFERAY_JVM_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

This doesn't look like it would be enough from my experience...

If not provided enough, it can slow down or even crash without helpful logs telling you what happened.